# I have an allowed IP range to configure dockers and I want to export docker daemon on a port

Tags: docker, centos7

**I have an allowed IP range to configure dockers and I want to export docker daemon on a port?**

I have exposed it using the standard way on **2375** port the docker connects on docker `-H tcp://localhost:2375 ps`
but when I connect using ip address or *hostname* it doesnot work
docker `-H tcp://hostname:2375 ps`

This command doesn't work

Comment: May be you iptables rules are not correctly saved, as if you have exposed the daemon on port 2375, it would have to work !
Can you share the way you have exposed the docker daemon on the port 2375, may be there is some mistake in it !

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the docker daemon to listen on port 2375, so something like:

> dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock

then you need to tell the docker client how to connect to the server. A common way to do so is using the DOCKER_HOST environment variable. Like

> export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.101:2375
>
> docker info

Note, you need to change 192.168.99.101 to the IP address of your server.

You also need to make sure that the server does not block port 2375 with its firewall.

Comment: that what is already done.

when we use command "dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock" we can export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2375 from save server.

but when we try export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://<server ip>:2375 from the same server it refuse the connection and same happen from other servers. other servers can telnet